# Line continuation and commenting out

Tags: vimrc

This is a part in my `.vimrc` that is used to change appearance of tabs to `→` (arrow right) and spaces to `·` (dot).

```
set list
set listchars=
  \tab:→\ ,
  \space:·,
  \nbsp:·,
  \extends:›,
  \precedes:‹
```

But if I comment out the first line, it stops working:

```
set list
set listchars=
  " \tab:→\ ,
  \space:·,
  \nbsp:·,
  \extends:›,
  \precedes:‹
```

Is it possible to fix it? That is, to make each line can be commented out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line continuation comment syntax in vim script is `"\` , documented at `:help line-continuation-comment`:

```
set list
set listchars=
  "\ \tab:→\ ,
  \space:·,
  \nbsp:·,
  \extends:›,
  \precedes:‹
```

The `"\`  is parsed as one token of three characters.  For example, `"\tab` does not begin a line continuation comment.

Comment: OPs case highlights another quirk of continuation lines: adding a regular comment (`"`) anywhere results in all following continuation lines becoming part of the comment. This can actually be useful. For example, when using the Decho debugging plugin. The plugin has commands that automatically comment out it's debug/print statements. But it won't comment out any additional continuation lines added by the user. Thanks to the aforementioned behavior, though, things work fine (though it looks "wrong").